# Arcpy code does everything but won't stop running in the end

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I wrote a geoprocessing code using arcpy that works fine, but after the last geoprocessing tool (export table to excel) won't continue to the last task (print("Done")) although table is eported to .xls. What could be the cause?

Last part of the code:

```
from arcpy.sa import *
ZonalStatisticsAsTable(in_zone_data = r"C:\Users\Tim\Downloads\OB\OB\OB.shp", zone_field = "OB_UIME", in_value_raster = workingDirrectory + "/extract.tif", out_table = workingDirrectory + "/TableZonal")

arcpy.conversion.TableToExcel(Input_Table = workingDirrectory + "/TableZonal", Output_Excel_File = workingDirrectory + "/zonal_precipitation.xls" )

print("Done") #this part is not executed
```

Comment: what happens if you put a print statement before your geoprocessing? do you have something going on that changes the stdout location (i.e., screen vs. printing console outputs to a file?)

Comment: It works before the geoprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

try defining it as a function and then call the the function.

```
from arcpy.sa import *
def zonal_stat():
ZonalStatisticsAsTable(in_zone_data = r"C:\Users\Tim\Downloads\OB\OB\OB.shp", zone_field = "OB_UIME", in_value_raster = workingDirrectory + "/extract.tif", out_table = workingDirrectory + "/TableZonal")

arcpy.conversion.TableToExcel(Input_Table = workingDirrectory + "/TableZonal", Output_Excel_File = workingDirrectory + "/zonal_precipitation.xls" )

return "done"
```

Comment: Why would this change anything?